# Push to my repo from another PC

Tags: github

I have a repo that I've created at home from my PC. Now I'm at the PC from my company, I cloned the repo and when I tried to push I got this error:

```
remote: Permission to danielfpedro/mayhem-app.git denied to ag.interagir@gmail.c
om.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/danielfpedro/mayhem-app/': The reque
sted URL returned error: 403
```

The problem is, I dont know where github is geting the reference to this username **ag.interagir@gmail**, and I dont know how to change this.

I've also added the ssh-key from the PC of the my company to the github account.

I know this is pretty basic but I researched a lot and can't find nothing useful

Comment: Was the company machine wiped and reinstalled for you? It sounds like you may have another user's configuration kicking around...

Comment: ye how can I can change the current user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont needed change the user, I just added the user from my company to colaborators of the repo. Simple like that but can be useful for someone.